# live('click' not working but .click( workig in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am using `jquery version 1.3.2`. i face a strange issue. in IE9 my application works fine , but in IE8 this functon not working

```
jQuery('.mutulafriends').live('click',function(){});
```

i just put an alert inside this function but not working , seems it is not identifying the `click`. in the console i can see a error

```
SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. 
jquery-1.3.2.min.js, line 12 character 12949
```

when i use this function with the alert

```
jQuery('.mutulafriends').click(function(){
    alert("");
});
```

works perfectly. but the error is also shown:

```
SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. 
jquery-1.3.2.min.js, line 12 character 12949
```

seems that error is not affecting the `click`. i know that for jquery version 1.3.2 `live('change'` is not working but why `live('clck'` is not working? any ideas , please help. thanks in advance. this is my HTML. it may be too long , but i think it may help.

```
        <div class="component-list-wrapper">

        <?php if(is_array($result) && count(array_filter($result)) > 0) {
            foreach($result as $record) {
                ?>

            <div class="eliment-component-list eliment-divider">
                <div class="user-profile-img-holder">
                    <img alt="Profile image"
                        src=<?php if(isset($record['ProfileImg'])){echo $img_url.md5($record['ProfileID'])."/default/".$record['ProfileImg'];}else{echo $this->config->item('ivory_img_path')."/thumb-img.png";} ?> />
                </div>
                <div class="user-des-container">
                    <div class="user-des-left">
                        <div class="namecontainer">
                            <label class="darkcolour-large"><?php echo $record['FirstName']; if($record['PrivacySettingFriend']){echo " ".$record['LastName'];} ?></label> <label
                                class="lblsub"><?php echo $record['StateName'].', '.$record['CityName']; ?></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="friendcontainer">
                            <label img_url="<?php echo $img_url; ?>" req_type="recieved" friend_id="<?php echo $record['ProfileID']; ?>" class="darkcolour margine-top20 mutulafriends btndialogMutualFriends"><?php if(!isset($record['CommonFriendCount'])){echo "0 Friends in Common";}else if($record['CommonFriendCount']!=1){echo  $record['CommonFriendCount']."  Friends in Common";}else{echo  $record['CommonFriendCount']."  Friend in Common";} ?></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="user-des-right">
                        <div class="user-des-right-inner">
                            <img width="13" height="13" class="btnDialogDelete request_del_dialog_open_but" req_type="recieved" prof_friend_id="<?php echo $record['ProfileFriendID']; ?>"
                                src="<?php echo $this->config->item('ivory_img_path'); ?>close_button.png"
                                alt="Profile image">
                            <div class="button-wrapper">
                                <input type="button" class="btnRequest btn-white-small request_accept_dialog_open_but" name="" prof_friend_id="<?php echo $record['ProfileFriendID']; ?>"
                                    tabindex="123456" value="Accept">                                       
                            </div>
                            <div class="button-wrapper">
                                <input type="button" class="btnDialogAssign btn-grey-small request_decline_dialog_open_but" prof_friend_id="<?php echo $record['ProfileFriendID']; ?>" 
                                    name="" tabindex="123456" value="Decline">                                  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php }
        } else {?>

            <div class="no-records-found">No records found</div>

            <?php } ?>

        </div>
```

Comment: `.live()` together with `click` is working just fine with jQuery 1.3.2: http://jsfiddle.net/MgfLr/ There must be something else that is considered an `invalid argument`. What exactly is in the line 12 that the error is pointing to.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why you're using 1.3.2 instead of the latest 1.7.1?

Answer (score 1):

try using a the latest jQuery. It *might* solve your problems. There might be some bugs/deficiencies in that version that could have been addressed in the later versions of jQuery.

the current version as of this answer is 1.7.2 and [`.live()` has been deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/), and it's replacement is [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Also, *I pretty much assume* you are relying solely on the end error alert, which ends up in the jQuery library. It's not very informative. check your stack traces to check where your errors might possibly originate. try adding break points to know what the values are at a certain part of execution. I have confidence in jQuery and it might just be that you have provided some wrong values to it. check for typos also.

Answer (score 0):

Your class 'mutulafriends' doesnt required dynamic binding,so 'click' is enough i think

Wrap it in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         jQuery('.mutulafriends').click(function(){
           alert('And update your JQuery to the latest one :=)');

       });
});
```

//Delegate method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
             jQuery('div.component-list-wrapper').delegate('.mutulafriends','click',function(){
               alert('And update your JQuery to the latest one :=)');

           });
    });
```

Live or delegate methods are used only for latebindings which means elements that are generated after page load,Eg generated via an ajax call

Comment: no actually this has a pagination feature too . so elements are created dynamically .  and also this is inside $(document).ready(function() . my problem is why the live('click' is not working ???